# conditional deletion of mail from server

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, email

In my rails app I have mail receiver implemented with [Mailman](https://github.com/titanous/mailman/blob/master/USER_GUIDE.md) gem on top of POP3 protocol, which fetches all new messages from server and deletes them. However I don't want to delete messages by default from inbox, but rather fetch a new message, feed it to my internal function and if it returns true delete the message from server. Is it possible with POP3?

Comment: qoute from http://rubydoc.info/github/titanous/mailman/file/USER_GUIDE.md#Receivers states "The POP3 receiver is enabled when the Mailman.config.pop3 hash is set. It will poll every minute by default (this can be changed with Mailman.config.poll_interval). After new messages are processed, they will be deleted from the server. No copy of messages will be saved anywhere after processing. If you want to keep a copy of messages, it is recommended that you use a mail retriever with the Maildir receiver. You could also use Gmail and set it to keep messages after they have been retrieved with POP3."

Comment: seems you must use Maildir, or Gmail

Comment: Or any other account that has "keep messages" setting